# Log Client Ciphersuite in HAProxy

Tags: logging, haproxy, cipher

We know of log configurations that can log negotiated cipher-suite info in successful connections.

But what we need to do is to log the client cipher-suite info that HAProxy gets hold of during TLS Handshake, whether or not the connection negotiation is eventually successful.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Try to add %sslc variable to log format. http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#8.2.4

Comment: @Vadim Thanks for the response. We have done that, however it logs cipher suite only if connections are successful. If negotiations fail leading to unsuccessful TLS, it does not log.

Comment: If there will be no way with logs then use tcpdump )